# require that all merges take place via a merge request

Tags: gitlab

How can gitlab-ce be configured to require that all merges take place via a merge request, regardless of source/target branch? So, for example, even if just git itself is used to to interact with the remote repo, I would like to prohibit merges, unless they take place via a merge request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Gitlab 8.10 the branch protection feature was improved with [Wildcard Branch Protection](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/protected_branches.html), allowing repositories to protect branches based on their names, for example `release-*` protects any branch which starts with `release-`.

You can use this to set a `*` rule allowing only the Masters to make the merge. This will force any non Master user of the repo to open a merge request in order to get their changes into the repo.

Mind that you would need to limit who are the Masters.

Comment: That sounds possibly "good enough". The use case that this doesn't allow is: say a developer would like to branch off of the "issue" branch and parcel out some logical chunk of the work to another developer. These two could then work on merging this work back into the issue branch. I would like to allow that situation without the intervention of a Master, but require that the code goes back into the issue branch with a merge request, so there's documentation, traceability, discussion, etc. Also, this solution requires the Masters to "follow the rules", which doesn't always happen :-)

Comment: The two developers could have all the discussion, code review and change suggestion, etc, through the Merge request. It's not exactly what you have proposed but I believe that Merge requests have all the tools to make it work. 
You are right about the Masters "following the rules" but with some evangelization  and time the culture will get to their heads and transparency will thrive.